# How to fetch unread notifications first and then read notifications in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to fetch all notifications of a user from the database. But I want to fetch them filtered with unread notifications first and then read notifications.
Let's say, I have 3 unread notifications for a user with one read notifications. Then I will fetch all notifications where unread 3 notifications will come first in the collection and then the read one.
I don't see any eloquent way of doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all notifications fetching unread first, you need to apply `orderBy` on `read_at`

```
$notifications = auth()->user()->notifications()
                               ->orderBy('read_at', 'asc')
                               ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                               ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

By a simple array of collections Like this :

```
$res = [
            'unread' => auth()->user()->unreadnotifications
            'read' => auth()->user()->notifications()->whereNotNull('read_at')->get(),
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to override the notifications() function of the notifiable model. Example:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(DatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')->orderByRaw('-read_at');
    }
}
```

The negative before 'read_at' will sort unread notification first and then read notifications in descending order in MySQL databases.